# Windows Phone 8.1, using Map (not Map Control)

Tags: routes, bing-maps

**Windows Phone 8.1**, using Map (not Map Control) how to display the routes between two locations? Last few days I am looking for it but the start location is being the current position(which I don't want) and for end location I use GeocodeQuery which has SearchTerm property, whereas I gave to pass my own location (like Mumbai To Banglore and it must show the route and also different routes available, if possible) and like SearchTerm just by passing the name it returns the GeoCoordinate.

Current Code:

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        List MyCoordinates = new List();
        RouteQuery MyQuery = null;
        GeocodeQuery Mygeocodequery = null;

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.GetCoordinates();
        Map Mymap = new Map();

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private async void GetCoordinates()
    {
        // Get the phone's current location.
        Geolocator MyGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        MyGeolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 5;
        Geoposition MyGeoPosition = null;
        try
        {
            MyGeoPosition = await MyGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            MyCoordinates.Add(new GeoCoordinate(MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Longitude));
            MyMap.ZoomLevel = 11;
            Mygeocodequery = new GeocodeQuery();


            Mygeocodequery.SearchTerm = "Mumbai";
            Mygeocodequery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, MyGeoPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);
            Mygeocodequery.QueryCompleted += Mygeocodequery_QueryCompleted;
            Mygeocodequery.QueryAsync();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Location is disabled in phone settings or capabilities are not checked.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Something else happened while acquiring the location.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    void Mygeocodequery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            MyQuery = new RouteQuery();
            MyCoordinates.Add(e.Result[0].GeoCoordinate);
            MyQuery.Waypoints = MyCoordinates;
            MyQuery.QueryCompleted += MyQuery_QueryCompleted;
            MyQuery.QueryAsync();
            Mygeocodequery.Dispose();
        }
    }

         void MyQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Route MyRoute = e.Result;
            MapRoute MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
            MyMap.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);
            MyQuery.Dispose();
        }
    }


    }
```

In the above code I wish to pass my start location similar like SearchTerm property which will identify the Latitude and Longitude. 
Kindly help,
Thanks.